# How to force Visual Studio to use the whole namespace instead of a partial namespace when implenting an interface in vb .net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to figure out if there is an option in visual studio to instead of adding partial namespaces when implementing an interface in vb .net, to add the whole namespace.
That "feature" annoys me all the time...

Library: MyLib

```
Namespace Example.Tes1
  Public Interface IA
    Sub Test()
  End Interface
End Namespace
```

Thats what happens normaly:

```
Public Class B
  Implements IA

  Sub Test() Implements Test1.IA.Test
  End Sub

End Class
```

And thats what i would like to do visual studio for me instead of editing the namespaces by myself.

```
Public Class B
  Implements IA

  Sub Test() Implements MyLib.Example.Test1.IA.Test
  End Sub

End Class
```

Another option i would be ok with is if just the interface name would be there like this:

```
Public Class B
  Implements IA

  Sub Test() Implements IA.Test
  End Sub

End Class
```

Is anyone aware of how to teach visual studio to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you import the namespace that houses the interface at the top of the class code file, then VS (2012 and 2013) will only use the interface in the Implements clause.

Comment: Thats the point, it doesnt do that. If i didnt import the namespace of the interface i wouldn't be able to write "Implements IA"

Comment: hmm, wel, it works for me.  dunno what else to tell you.

Comment: ok, i admit, sometimes it works, but for whatever reason sometimes it doesnt, especially in bigger projects. i just tried to reproduce it with a simple example but i couldnt, but i can reproduce it on multiple live solutions. strange

Comment: @Epicycle Do you perhaps have the same interface names in different namespaces that are being imported (namespaces can also be globally imported on the references tab in project properties)?  I've never seen VS qualify the interface name unless is needed to for some reason.